# Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Tags: python, discord.py

I got this error between testing my discord bot. I am making bot to send random Pokémon data. I granted my bot administer and It's work fine but when I am disable administer permission I got an error

I try to find what specific permission that I should granted to my bot but I granted all permission except
administer and it's not working. I need to fix this error by give him specific permission that isn't admin
Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Here is my code for command section:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@bot.command()
   async def randompoke(ctx):
   url="https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + str(random.randint(1,898))
   data = requests.get(url).json()
   name = data['name']
   image = data['sprites']['front_default']
   type = data['types'][0]['type']['name']

   embed_randompoke=discord.Embed(title="Random Pokemon", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(245, 233, 12))
   embed_randompoke.set_thumbnail(url=image)
   embed_randompoke.add_field(name="Name:", value=f" {name} ", inline=False)
   embed_randompoke.add_field(name="ID:", value=f" {data['id']} ", inline=False)
   embed_randompoke.add_field(name="Type:", value=f" {type} ", inline=False)
   embed_randompoke.set_footer(text=f"At timestamp ", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
   await ctx.reply(embed=embed_randompoke)

   bot.run(token, reconnect=True)
```

thank!

Comment: If it works with admin perm, then just give admin perm.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this all of your code/are you sure that the error occurs in this part of the code? Could it be that the channel in which you tried to execute the command only allows administrators to write in?

Answer (score -1):

If the bot works when the `Administrator` perm is enabled, keep it enabled.

You can use [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions) for better calcification on Discord permissions.

Comment: If server owners want to decide whether to add the bot to their server, and they see that it requires administrator permission, they might want to decide not to add the bot to their server, so this isn't a good solution.

Comment: If you read the problem, they say the bot will only work with the admin perm. I suggested the above as well as linking to the docs for perms.